# Insert UITableViewCell With Animation and Scroll to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

My requirement is simple , i just need to add a `TableCell` with `rightRowAnimation` and scroll to it. It happens as long as i am with within `tableView` height , as i cross the height of `tableView` to add cell further , it adds cell but displays no animation when scrolling to it.

Attached is a simple project with a `UITableView` for reference , Appreciate your help !!

[Sample Project with a simple UItableView and Add Button](https://app.box.com/s/cb95yad9cstdb5bg5hff3j1v0z2s8ymo)

**Code**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.dataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell1"];
    BOOL myBool = indexPath.row%2 == 0;
    if(myBool){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


-(IBAction)addTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.dataArray addObject:@"New Object"];
//    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.dataArray.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
//    [_tableView endUpdates];

    [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.dataArray.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You should add the relevant code snippet over here.

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow method for the animation.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
        cell.alpha = 0;
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
            cell.alpha = 1;
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 1, 1, 1);


           }];
}
```

change what ever your requirements

Comment: This will always animate the cell even when scrolling up and down, i specifically mentioned just to insert !!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to animate row put in table.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView transitionWithView:yourtablename
                          duration:5.1f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                        animations:^(void) {
                            [yourtablename reloadData];
                        } completion:NULL];
    });
}
```

**also you can change animation style.**

Comment: Question asks for animating every cell inserting while also scrolling to bottom , not only when the controller will appear on screen